# Linux bash - Regular Expression to find a string included between a static string and the first number

Tags: sed, ls

I need to extract in linux bash from a string a set of characters which are included between a static string and the first number.

A simple example should be helpful:

**Base string**: hello-world-my_name-1.0.jar

**Static string**: hello-world-

**Target**: my_name

I'm trying with

```
ls *.jar | sed 's/(?<=hello-world-)(.+?(?=-[0-9]))/\1/'
```

but unfortunately I can't understand where I'm wrong

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Also, check [Learning Regular Expresions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) here at Stackoverflow.

Comment: Where is the string stored? In a variable, in a file? Bash or POSIX shell? Bash/shell only or using external binaries such as sed, grep, awk?

Answer (score 0):

Match everything, capture your middle string in a group and replace everything with the captured value:

```
printf 'hello-world-my_name-1.0.jar\n' | sed 's/hello-world-\([^0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

Output:

```
my_name-
```

If the hyphen needs to be replaced too, match it outside the group; or remove it with a second pattern:

```
printf 'hello-world-my_name-1.0.jar\n' | sed 's/hello-world-\([^0-9]*\)-.*/\1/'
# or
printf 'hello-world-my_name-1.0.jar\n' | sed 's/hello-world-\([^0-9]*\).*/\1/;s/-$//'
```

Alternatively, if the middle string cannot contain hyphens, add it to the character class:

```
printf 'hello-world-my_name-1.0.jar\n' | sed 's/hello-world-\([^0-9-]*\).*/\1/'
```